# Are there any way to create .net user controls for the purpose of using them on delphi forms?

Tags: .net, delphi

A .net user control could be used as a control in delphi VCL Forms projects? Resizing them in design time and calling its methods by strongly typing or by calling Invoke like methods at least.

I digged in COM technology but it's hard for me. I hope there is a more convenient way for .net to delphi interop.

Thanks.

Comment: It's no doubt possible. The obvious route is to expose the control as an ActiveX control. I'd expect that there would be an easier solution to solve your actual problem, whatever it happens to be.

Comment: Nex to the `JCL Classes`, you might also want to look in the commercial Hydra product from RemObjects, as it has been created to support the development of mixed-mode applications:  http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/mixedmode.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one way, and that is to host the .NET runtime into the Delphi application.

You can check out the [JCL classes](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/) which has code to do this hosting.

Once you've done that, you can ensure your control classes are [ComVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) by tagging them with the attribute:

```
[ComVisible]
public class SomeControl : UserControl
```

Then you'll have to construct the control from Delphi, how to do this via the JCL system I don't know as we've created our own wrappers. You should really check out the JCL classes for more details here.

There are some problems, however:

- Resizing doesn't always work, sometimes you'll have to handle the resized event in Delphi, and then manually ask the .NET control to resize itself accordingly
- Tabbing between textboxes doesn't always work, specifically Delphi code seems to regard the entire .NET control as a black box, and will tab out of it, never into it, and not inside it, except in some cases where it will.
- Keyboart shortcuts (Alt+O for open for instance) doesn't work, since Delphi is picking those up and doesn't understand that the .NET control has such things
- Exceptions from .NET code will bubble from .NET code into Delphi code as an external exception, and all exception detail have been lost along the way. This is the COM OleVariant wrapper generated code that the Delphi compiler injects that doesn't handle this correctly.

I would seriously consider whether you really want this. It is much easier to open a .NET window from Delphi code, and this will behave much more predictable.

Comment: yes, it looks much easier to keep .net controls in .net assembly.